# This code datasource configurarion in tomme is running without eclipse fine but when i run in eclipse then its giving error

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, datasource

i am using apache tomee datasource for connecting mysql to java.This will work without eclipse(juno) fine but when i running using eclipse then its giving error.
error can view in this url:http://www.docdroid.net/2xuj/errro.txt.html

This is my tomme.xml file

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <tomee>
              <Resource id="jdbc/mydb" type="DataSource">
                JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver    
                JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ops
                UserName root
                Password     
                JtaManaged true    
             </Resource>
            </tomee>
```

and web.xml

```
            <resource-ref>
             <description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
             <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name>
              <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
               <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
            </resource-ref>
```

and my servlet file containts

```
                Context initContext = new InitialContext();
          Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
          Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
          Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * From student_master");
          while(rs.next())
            out.println("the student name is"+rs.getString("SM_StudentName"));
```

This code i wrote for testing only.this code working without eclipse fine and one more things when i run this project in eclipse its giving exception of hsqldb not mysql you can view full stack trance here.
http://www.docdroid.net/2xuj/errro.txt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you configure the datasource in tomee.xml and with eclipse then you have to do  this 
steps also.

```
     Locate your TomEE server configuration in Workspace / Servers(Eclipse)
     Right-click the server project and select Import
     Select General - File System and click Next
     Browse to your <TomEE>/conf folder
     Select the following files for import: logging.properties, system.properties and            tomee.xml
      Click Finish to import the files.
       In the Servers tab, right-click the TomEE server and select Publish to publish the files to the Eclipse metadata folder
```

this will work.